# SQL Query to Sort Data Based on Maximum Value

Tags: mysql, query

Here is my dataset:

[image]

For any given 'time' (basically every second), about 3 to 5 'cell ids' are logged. What I need the know is the 'cell id' of the maximum 'ref signal _ received power' received for each timeset (second).

For example, the first timeset, 10:32:25, we see four 'cell ids', 420, 214, 284 & 323 and it is easy enough to see that the maximum 'ref signal _ received power' is -87.38 for the first timeset.  Now can we create an SQL query to do this for us?

I have hours of data so a programatic solution is very desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html). Some common ones are `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()`, and `DENSE_RANK()`. But I think the simplest solution for you is to use the [`FIRST_VALUE()` window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-first_value-function/) like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [time],
    FIRST_VALUE([cell id]) OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY [time]
        ORDER BY [ref signal _ received power] DESC
    )
FROM YourTable;
```

What the `FIRST_VALUE()` window function does is *group up* the rows by the field being partitioned on, and orders the rows within those partition groups by the field in the order by clause, and returns the first value of the field passed into the function (`cell id` in this case) from each row partition group. The distinct keyword then collapses the rows down to just a unique row per `time` and first `cell id`.

Note, if your data spans multiple dates, and you actually want a separate `cell id` for each distinct date and time, then you can just add the `date` field to the above query like so to break it out appropriately:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [date],
    [time],
    FIRST_VALUE([cell id]) OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY [date], [time]
        ORDER BY [ref signal _ received power] DESC
    )
FROM YourTable;
```

Also, just for good manageability and readability, and to reduce the chance of syntactical errors, you should name your columns without special characters (e.g. spaces) and not use reserved words (e.g. data types `date` and `time`) as the names.

Comment: Yes sir, that did the trick.  I even expanded on your code to add the LAT/LON to the query.  Noted your comments manageability and readability.  Thank you.

Comment: @user231744 Great! Glad to be of help!

Comment: @user231744 Note I just realized you're using MySQL. While the code is the same syntactically, I linked the wrong database system's documentation earlier. I just updated my answer so the documentation is relevant specifically to your database system. Sorry about that.